# How to set SwaggerUI/OpenApi - Api Version in Configuration with GroupedOpenApi

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a Java SpringBoot RestApi with SpringDoc and I have added new Versions. For the new versions I added the GroupedOpenApi Configuration Beans so I get a dropdown for the versions in SwaggerUI.

Now I also want to display the selected version number in the gray bubble next to the Api-name "Khbrn Api"

My configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig
{

    // -----------------------------
    // Public Methods
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI()
    {

        return new OpenAPI()

                .components(new Components())

                .info(new Info().title("Khbrn Api").description("Do stuff Api")
                        .version("12345")); // I try to make the version dynamic for each option in the dropdown

    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupV110()
    {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("1.1").pathsToMatch("/v110/**").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupV120()
    {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("1.2").pathsToMatch("/v120/**").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupV121()
    {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("1.2.1").pathsToMatch("/v121/**").build();
    }
}
```

As the result I want to change the grey version number(in this example its "12345") when I change the selected dropdown option.

[Swagger UI with Version Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITdAe.png)